# SQL Server 2008 Express - Got "The columns do not match an existing primary key or UNIQUE constraint" despite constraints being set

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2008-express

I have the following tables

```
ModuleClass ( <ModuleID>, <Section>, <Number>, StartDate, EndDate)
ClassEnrollment ( <ModuleID>, <Section>, <Term Code>, <User Name>, Role)
```

Now a ModuleClass entity can have more than one enrollment, so there is a 1 to M relationship. However, when attempting to define FK between ModuleClass and ClassEnrollment using ModuleID and Section, I get

> The columns in table ClassEnrollment do
>   not match an existing primary key or
>   UNIQUE constraint

However, both ModuleID and Section are participating in a PK constraint.

(I am using the Visual Database Tools to create the tables and specify the relationship).

What is a better way of representing this relationship?

Comment: Do ModuleId and Section make up the entire primary key or only part of it? Are the data types of the equivalent columns exactly the same?

Comment: Can you script out the two tables as `CREATE TABLE` statements, and add them to your question?

Comment: @Thomas, ModuleID and Section are part of the PK (the field in the <> are part of the PK)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I am using Visual Database Tools to create the table. Is there anyway I can see the underlying CREATE TABLE script?

Comment: @Extrakun - unfortunately, I'm not familiar with those tools, so I couldn't say.

Comment: @Extrakun - The key word is "part" of the PK. In order to reference a PK in an FK constraint, you have to reference the entire key which means all columns in the PK must exist in the FK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *looks* like the primary key of ModuleClass is a composite key consisting of three columns, (ModuleID, Section, Number). To set a foreign key reference to that table, you'll have to target all three of those columns.

To target all three of those columns, you'll need to include the column "Number" in the table ClassEnrollment. Then you can set

```
FOREIGN KEY (ModuleID, Section, Number) 
  REFERENCES ModuleClass (ModuleID, Section, Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't specify the FK relationship backwards?  This is an easy mistake to make using GUI visual tools.  You have to make sure that every row in ClassEnrollment references one row in ModuleClass.

If you specify the relationship in the reverse direction, you'll get exactly the error you reported.